Calculating ranges of correlation using correlation matrix and determinant
Say I have some random variables x,y,z where p(x,y) = .8, p(x,z) = .8. How can I find the maximal and minimal correlation between y,z: p(y,z)?
My first solution is to define the correlation between any two random variables as the cos of the angle formed between them. This gives me the ranges of .28<= p(y,z) <=1 using some trigonometry to rewrite cos(2theta), and by setting y=z.
However I also noticed that if I were to form the correlation matrix C, using the given values$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & .8 & .8 \\
.8 & 1 & p(y,z) \\
.8 & p(z,y) & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
$$
it so happends that det(C) = -p^2+1.28p-.28 = 0 would imply p(y,z) = .28 or p(y,z) = 1.
My understanding is that any correlation matrix must be semi-positive definite implying its determinant must be 0 or greater; which would imply the eigenvalues must be 0 or greater. But why is it that det(C) = 0 gives me the exact boundaries of correlation p(y,z), is it a coincidence?

To begin with, using "$p(x, y)$" is not a good notation to denote the correlation between $X$ and $Y$: a standard notation is $\rho_{X, Y}$. Now to your question, which is rather trivial: because the PSD constraint $\det(C) \geq 0$ (a quadratic inequality about $\rho$) would resolve to $0.28 \leq \rho \leq 1$, then the $\rho = 0.28$ and $\rho = 1$ of course correspond to the equality condition $\det(C) = 0$.

This is a FAQ.  I have identified a couple of threads that solve it.  The first one is exactly the same question but with slightly different constants in the matrix.  In this case your logic is incomplete: psd implies non-negative determinant, but not conversely.  It will help to notice that only one of the principal minors imposes any condition on $p$--namely the $2,3$ minor--and that's why your situation simplifies.
